# Nginx non-responsive while celery is running

Tags: python, django, nginx, redis, wsgi

I have a django app configured to run behind nginx using uWSGI.  On a separate machine I am running celery, and pushing long running tasks from the webserver to the task machine.  The majority of the task I/O is outbound http requests, which go on for an hour or more.  The task broker is redis.

When the tasks run for more than a minute or two, the webserver becomes unresponsive (503 errors).

There are no errors raised anywhere within the python app.  The tasks complete normally, after which the webserver continues handling requests.

Has anyone experienced this before, and if so, how did you deal with it?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> by default uWSGI starts with a single process and a single thread

From the [uwsgi docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#adding-concurrency-and-monitoring). Depending on your config this might cause the issue.

**UPDATE**: just noticed that you did not said uwsgi, but just wsgi - nevertheless depending on your wsgi implementation the issue might be caused by the same fact.

Comment: Sorry, it is indeed uWSGI (edited above).  We have it configured for multiprocessing.  Even if we didn't, I don't see why a single threaded web application would block after calling a celery task.  Or why the blocking wouldn't occur immediately, but rather after a few minutes.

Comment: Does this apply: the nginx uwsgi django box is the task machine and the http requests from celery hit this task machine? Or is the only connection between those two boxes redis and they have nothing else to do with each other?

Comment: The two boxes are connected only via redis.  There is a shared postgres database as well, but that lives on yet another box, and neither one seems to be having an issue maintaining the db connection.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out after a few days.  We were using a django app called django-health-check.  It has a component called health_check_celery3 that was in the installed apps.  This was having trouble loading while celery was running, and thus causing the whole app to stall.  After removing it, celery runs as it should.